# Unusually long username (possibly) causing comments to extend outside the the comments box

Tags: bug, comments, users

I happened upon [this question](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/40107/have-four-out-of-five-systematic-reviews-concluded-that-homeopathy-works) (from the HNQ list).

Most of the comments have extended beyond the comments box, and overlapped with the HNQ list.

> [image]

Gut feeling: The super long username (apparently reads "Peace be upon him" in Arabic, over and over) is causing the weird rendering; but other comments are affected too, so...

I use Chrome. Is anyone else seeing this?

Comment: Yes, it effs up Chrome for me.

Comment: I use firefox, same issue.

Comment: It's a known issue, I'm going to ping the right person directly.

Comment: I would like to mention that I already flagged that user on November 16th.

Comment: Huh, I am not experiencing it on Chrome. Chrome 62.0.3202.89 on Kubuntu 16.04.

Comment: It seems to be because of the hacky way (["Unicode magic"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/170970/occasionally-the-unicode-character-sequence-u200c-u200b-zwnj-zwsp-is-insert?noredirect=1&lq=1)) that comments are formatted for display: see on Meta [Stop inserting invisible characters into comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/295425)

Comment: I don't think user is at fault, nor that they should be obliged to change their desired username; let's fix the fault itself, i.e. the code which obviously doesn't work as expected. This is a SE (I suppose it's not skeptics-specific?) software bug, not user's responsibility. (I don't have the required fonts to display the text, so I can't reproduce it.)

Comment: Can reproduce on the latest Firefox and IE11, even after replacing the Unicode characters with a plain 'a' (all that matters is that its longer than the bounding box is wide).  Sprinking `overflow-wrap: break-word` liberally throughout the stylesheets didn't change anything either.

Comment: Either the username is changed by now, or I [can't reproduce the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nAZ9a.jpg). That's on the latest stable FF.

Comment: Apparently someone force-changed by username without telling me, and now I can't change it again because of the 30 day limit. Getting kinda fed up of this abuse. Was it Shog9 again? How can I find out?

Comment: < *Looks around innocently* >

Comment: Thanks, I was worried the harassment had started again. Can you change my name run user since I can't? Thanks.

Comment: @user41815 Yep, it's "user41815" .__.

Comment: Thanks, I mean can you change it from that to "user" because I can't and I don't want to be to user41815. Thanks.

Comment: @user41815 Nope, I'm not a Mod (or a Dev), just another user. If you need the name changed (and if you need to raise your complaint about the name being changed in the first place) you'll have to ping a Mod, either in the comments here (Sklivvz) or in in the [chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/311/hub-of-reason). Hope you get this resolved :-)

Comment: I feel like I've been Shog'ed again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because this is not Skeptics.SE specific,  I raised a bug report on [Meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/303408/long-display-name-with-no-spaces-breaks-design-of-comments). Kindly upvote it there,  for more visibility with the dev team.